# CSS attribute selectors not selecting

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a question but do not know if there is an answer as no-one seems to know.

I am trying to use CSS selectors ...

I have several divs on a web page who's class name ends with -modal and I select them using CSS selector

```
div[class$="-modal"] { CSS Properties ... }
```

and this works a treat. I also have three divs that end with -window (.one-window, .two-window etc ) and I try to select them with

```
div[class$="-window"] { CSS Properties ... }
```

I get nothing. If I style them using the conventional

```
.one-window, .two-window { CSS Properties ... }
```

this works fine.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is `two-window` the only class assigned to these items?

Comment: Why don't you use multiple classes instead of dash-separated names?

Comment: Use `div[class$="-window"],div[class*="-window "] { CSS Properties ... }`, does it work?

Comment: maybe some other rule might be overwriting your `$=-window` rules, maybe a class somewhere?

Comment: Please accept the answer below by clicking the check mark instead of editing this question to tell people that the issue is resolved. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 6):

> [**CSS3 Selectors - 6.3.2. Substring matching attribute selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)
>
> [att$=val]
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Therefore `*-window` has to be the last class appearing in the attribute in order for it to be selected.

```
<div class="foo bar one-window">...</div>
```

The above HTML would be selected because the attribute ends with `*-window` - [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/a4rz3/).

```
div[class$="-window"] {
    /* .. */
}
```

---

```
<div class="one-window foo bar">text..</div>
```

Whereas the above *wouldn't* be selected - [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/a4rz3/1/)

```
div[class$="-window"] {
    /* .. */
}
```

---

Possible solutions would be to re-order the class attribute values to ensure that `*-window` appears at the end. Alternatively, you could use the following attribute selector in order to select attributes that **contain** at least one occurrence of the value  `-window`. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/a4rz3/2/) .. this assumes that no other classes contain the substring `-window`. Highly uncommon but still probable.

```
div[class*="-window"] {
    color:red;
}
```